# Why produces Excel Formula with range an Error?

Tags: excel

I use the following Formula in excel (Where Names is the Range A6:A20 - see the picture below):

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(Names<>"";MATCH(Names;Names;0));ROW(Names)-ROW(A6)+1)>0))
```

This gives me the Error `#Wert!`. In don't find the reason.

The Output should be the count of distinct values in Range A6:A20 (=Names)

When I extract the part

```
=IF(Names<>"";MATCH(Names;Names;0))
```

it produces the same error.

Ranges `Names`:

[image]

Comment: Please translate the formulas into English.

Comment: I think the second formula is `=IF(Names<>"",Match(Names,Names,0))`

Comment: This is probably an array formula the needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Also please show what the expected output should be.

Comment: I have translated it to english. The Output should be the count of distinct values in Range A6:A20

Comment: Then use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  The formula needs to be Array Entered.

Comment: Thanks Scott - this was the problem.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Can you add your solution as a Post - so I can mark it as the solution.